# FileZilla 3.7.2 on Windows 8 64bit

Tags: windows, 64-bit, filezilla

I would like to ask if FileZilla 3.7.2 on Windows 8 (64bit) possible?
Anyone here tried to install one?

Comment: Are you talking about the FileZilla client or the server? What happened when you tried to install it?

Comment: I'm referring to the FileZilla client sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible.

I have it installed on my Windows 8.1 (x64 box).

Additionally, although the [download page for FileZilla client](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client) doesn't currently state that the installer works for Windows 8, the [current Client install instructions from the documentation](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Client_Installation#Installing_on_Windows) was created based on a Windows 8 install.

> Please note: All screenshots are from Windows 8. Yours may look different, but the functionality is the same.

Also, from the documantation under "[Choosing the right download](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Client_Installation#Choosing_the_right_download)":

> ...On Windows Vista, 7 or **8**, you might need to confirm an
>   additional UAC prompt to start the installer.

Comment: Okay sir, I have here FileZilla 3.7.3 win 32bit installer. I will try this on my Windows8 64bit machine.

I'll let you know for the results.
Thanks!

Comment: It works fine, trust me. Windows can install 32 bit programs on 64 bit machines just fine.

Comment: I'm guessing it was the lame "Yes it works - Extra characters to satisfy 30 limit" answer before your edit.  And while _I_ trust you, why not expand your post a little with some sources showing it's known to be compatible?

Comment: Thanks Joe for your reply. Done installing and its working fine so far. Yeah you're right, in fact Windows has separate folder (Program Files (x86)) for 32bit apps you installed. Cheers!